# Solving $dx/dt=0.2x^2\left(1-x/3\right)$ for the initial condition $x(0)=x_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the system $$\frac{dx}{dt}=0.2x^2\left(1-\frac{x}{3}\right),$$ if $x(0)=x_0$. This is a separable ODE, and my attempt is below.
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=0.2x^2\left(1-\frac{x}{3}\right) \\
\int\frac{dx}{x^2(3-x)}&=\frac{1}{15}\int dt \\
\int \frac{1/9}{x}+\frac{1/3}{x^2}+\frac{1/3}{3-x} \ dx&=\frac{1}{15}\int dt \\
\frac{1}{9}\ln(x)-\frac{1}{3x}-\frac{1}{3}\ln(3-x)&=\frac{t}{15} +C, \ \ \ C\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{align}
However, I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Why not put $t=0, x=x_0$ to find $C$?

Comment: @Tavish I have done this, but I am unsure how to present my solution in a more formal form e.g. $x(t)=...$ This leads me to suspect that I have made an error.

Comment: In solutions to many differential equations, the dependent variable cannot be isolated.

Comment: Once you have substituted $t=0$ and $x = x_0$ to solve for $C$, you have finished. The ODE is solved, though I reckon there is little hope to be able to make $x$ the subject of the solution, if that is what you want.

Comment: @Logos Is this possible? I cannot seem to make $x$ the subject of the solution

Comment: I do not think you can make $x$ the subject. It is theoretically possible, but not practically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the implicit exuation which means it can be written in a form $F(x,y)=0$. As you can see, you cannot do anything more meaningful. All this informations tell us that your solution which you have written at the end is final. Remember that we not always can have solution in a form $x(t)=\ldots.$